# How to prove any set belong to a $V_\alpha$ in cumulative hierarchy

Tags: set-theory

I find that most proofs in cumulative hierarchy that any set belongs to some $V_\alpha$ of ordinals are inconclusive. One online source assumes it be axiom. Is it really axiom?

Comment: What precisely do you mean by the last question? (As for the rest, this is a consequence of the axiom of foundation. And it is fairly easy to see that it is in fact equivalent to this axiom.)

Comment: Again, I do not understand what it is you are trying to covey by that expression.

Comment: See the treatment of this in Set Theory: An Introduction To Independence Proofs, by K.Kunen.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Where in Kunen are you referring to? On page 95, he defines $WF=\bigcup \{R(\alpha): \alpha\in On\}$ with the following comment that the well-founded sets are defined to be those in some $R(\alpha)$. So is there a proof. Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*EDIT: The following is based on the OP's comments below.*

Let's look in detail at my claim $(i)$, below, which is really the heart of the argument (everything else is just leveraging this claim in a straightforward way). To repeat:

> $(i)$ If $a$ is not cumulative, then $a$ has some non-cumulative element.

What does this use about the cumulative hierarchy?

Well, here's the proof of $(i)$: suppose every element of $a$ is cumulative. To each element $b$ of $a$, associate an ordinal $\beta_b$ such that $b\in V_{\beta_b}$ - e.g. let $\beta_b$ be the least such ordinal (which exists since the ordinals are well-ordered; alternatively, use choice).

The collection $B=\{\beta_b: b\in a\}$ is a set *(by replacement - consider the formula $\varphi(x, y)\equiv$"$x\in a$ and $y=\beta_x$")*, so there is an ordinal $\gamma$ greater than every ordinal in $B$ *(why? this is essentially [Burali-Forti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burali-Forti_paradox))*.

Now think about $V_\gamma$. Since $\gamma>\beta_b$ for each $b\in a$, we have $b\in V_\gamma$ for each $b\in a$. In other words, $a\subseteq V_\gamma$. But then $a\in V_{\gamma+1}$, so $a$ is cumulative. **And we're done**.

${}{}$

Now what did we use about the ordinals and the cumulative hierarchy, here?

- There is no biggest ordinal - this was needed to construct $\gamma+1$ from $\gamma$.
- More significantly, any *set* of ordinals has some upper bound - this was needed to construct $\gamma$ in the first place.
- The levels of the cumulative hierarchy are nested: if $\alpha_0>\alpha_1$ then $V_{\alpha_0}\supseteq V_{\alpha_1}$. This was needed to argue that $b\in V_\gamma$ for each $b\in a$.
- We used the fact that every subset of one level of the cumulative hierarchy is an element of the next level, that is, $\mathcal{P}(V_\alpha)\subseteq V_{\alpha+1}$; this was needed to argue that $a\in V_{\gamma+1}$ since $a\subseteq V_\gamma$.
- Additionally, if we want to avoid choice, we need that the ordinals are well-ordered, so that we could in fact pick $\beta_b$ for each $b\in a$.

---

I'm not sure what proofs you're reading, but here's an outline of  the usual argument (you should be able to fill in the gaps):

We want to prove the following statement, in ZFC *(but we'll improve this below)*:

> For every $x$, there is some ordinal $\alpha$ such that $x\in V_\alpha$.

(Note that this requires us to *define* $V_\alpha$ in terms of $\alpha$ in the language of set theory; this isn't hard *(HINT: transfinite recursion)* but it does need to be done, and if you haven't seen it before it's worth trying to do.)

Crucially, we will use the [**axiom of foundation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity); this says that for any nonempty set $s$, there is an element $t\in s$ which is "minimal" in the sense that $t\cap s=\emptyset$ (there may be more than one such $t$, but there has to be at least one). Intuitively, foundation rules out things like infinite descending sequences of sets $w_0\ni w_1\ni w_2\ni ...$. **Foundation is necessary here**; in fact, over ZF minus foundation, the axiom of foundation is *provably equivalent* to the statement "every set is in the cumulative hierarchy."

---

OK, on to the proof sketch!

Say that a set $x$ is **non-cumulative** if $x$ is not in any $V_\alpha$ (and note that "non-cumulative" is in fact expressible in the language of ZFC). The key observation is:

> $(i)$ If $x$ is non-cumulative, then $x$ has some non-cumulative element.

Proof sketch: prove the contrapositive. If every element of $x$ is in some level of the cumulative hierarchy, show that $x$ also is in the cumulative hierarchy *(HINT: find a level $V_\alpha$ at which all elements of $x$ have shown up ...)*.

Now we iterate this, to show:

> $(ii)$ If $x$ is noncumulative then there is a sequence of sets $x_0\ni x_1\ni x_2\ni ...$

Namely, take $x_0=x$ and let $x_{i+1}$ be any noncumulative element of $x_i$ (which will exist by induction on $i$).

But then:

> $(iii)$ We're done, since this contradicts Foundation.

---

Note that this argument implicitly used the axiom of choice, in step $(ii)$, to pick $x_{i+1}$ from $x_i$. One natural question is:

> Can we do this without choice?

This time, the answer is **yes**: while choice makes things simpler, it's not necessary at all.

[**Replacement**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_replacement) is your friend here (incidentally, even though choice is "flashier" there are many senses in which *replacement* is really the "powerhouse" axiom). With replacement, we can prove that there is a set $y$ (e.g. the transitive closure of $x$) such that

- $x\subseteq y$, and
- $y$ is **transitive**: if $u\in v$ and $v\in y$ then $u\in y$.

(This is a good exercise.) Now given this $y$, look at the subset $\hat{y}$ consisting of all non-cumulative elements of $y$. Then $\hat{y}$ violates the axiom of foundation:

> $(iv)$ If $a\in y$, then $a$ is noncumulative, so by $(i)$ we know that $a$ has a noncumulative element $b$; but since $y$ is transitive, we have $b\in y$, and since $b$ is noncumulative we have $b\in\hat{y}$, and hence $b\in a\cap\hat{y}$. So **for every $a\in\hat{y}$, we have $a\cap\hat{y}\not=\emptyset$**, which is exactly what foundation says **can't** happen.

I believe that replacement is in fact necessary, but [set theory without replacement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo_set_theory) is quite weird, and I'm not confident of my claim.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68507/discussion-between-noah-schweber-and-user1006).